# UISearchBar Cancel Button Not Working

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar on my MKMapView that I'm going to use to search annotations.  I'm having trouble getting the cancel button to work.  I create the search bar in my viewDidLoad method like this:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,44);
    searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = NO;
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];
```

And I've implemented this method for the cancel button:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You haven't assigned the search bar delegate.

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Please set delegate to self as in code i posted because search bar is unable to find delegate through which it calls the cancel button method.

```
searchBar.delegate=self;
```

and in .h file set the delegate as `<UISearchBarDelegate>`

Hope this helps.